# Using a variable to set a ScrollTop with animate function

Tags: javascript, variables, scrolltop

I have a series of divs that collapse and open and I'd like the browser to scroll to the top of the open divs.

I'm trying to do this using anchor links and having the anchor link saved in a variable "scrollClass" but my code is not working.  When I test the console log however, it outputs exactly what I want it to output.  I'm not sure if this is a syntax situation or not.

I'd appreciate any help that I can get here.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
$('.discover-btn-open, .discover-btn-open a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var currentElement = $(document.activeElement);
var scrollClass = $(this).closest('.discover-inner').find('#discover- anchor').attr('href');
$(".discover-inner").removeClass("discover-inner-open");
$(this).closest(".discover-inner").addClass("discover-inner-open");
console.log(scrollClass);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(scrollClass).offset().top - 100}, 450);
});

$('.discover-close, .discover-close a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest(".discover-inner").removeClass("discover-inner-open");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe log `$(scrollClass).offset()`

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting attribute `href` to `scrollClass` and when you try to use it as an element it won't work. Try removing the `attr("href")` part and using the `.offset` then.

You could also just trigger the click on the `anchor` element you want to scroll to through jQuery.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this helped a lot. Getting the scroll coordinate right away was the way to go.

Comment: var scrollClass = $(this).closest('.discover-inner').offset().top;                                          $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scrollClass -100}, 450);

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working